# How can I show `relativenum` at the end of a line?

Tags: neovim

I'm in neovim, and I've got relative numbering turned on so my files look something like:

```java
...
    2 public class Main {
    1     public static void main(String[] args) {
  17          if (args.length == 1 && args[0].equals("bench")) {  <-- my cursor is on this line
    1             List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    2             int target = 10;
...
```

Which is great, but it would be nice to have the line numbers at the *end* of the line, since that's usually where my eyes are when I'm editing code and wanting to hope around with `5j` or `32k` or similar.

So the ideal situation would look like:

```java
...
public class Main { 2
    public static void main(String[] args) { 1
        if (args.length == 1 && args[0].equals("bench")) { 17   <-- my cursor is on this line
            List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); 1
            int target = 10; 2
...
```

Except you wouldn't be able to select the trailing line numbers and they'd be formatted so they don't get in the way, a bit like [rust-analyzer](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer)'s type hints show up in blue after a line of code:

[image: rust-analyzer type hints in blue after every line of code]

Or also similarly to how you can setup `listchars` to show newline characters at the end of the line:

[image: newline and space characters shown in vim with listchars set]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I've removed the "plugin request" since that part would be off-topic (answers can still refer to plugins as solutions, however).

Comment: Ah okay, my apologies :thumbs-up:

Comment: This is a very unique and weirdly useful ask. I don't have the time right now to investigate but I suspect it can be done with virtual text. [This post](https://jdhao.github.io/2021/09/09/nvim_use_virtual_text/) may be of help.

Comment: Thanks @kadekai, that post's definitely helpful. Seeing as this post isn't getting much traction I might try implement it myself and post here if I get a plugin working.